# Output time stamp to log file with Terminal

Tags: python, bash, terminal

I want to set a time-stamp on `log.txt` file for every output line. It's doing what I want it to do in terminal output. how would I go about to set the time-stamp in `log.txt` file?

**Command:**

```
python ig.py |& tee -a log.txt | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
```

**Terminal Output:**

```
[2017-04-19 08:38:48] DEBUG:__main__:Liking 1494171280764517709
[2017-04-19 08:38:49] DEBUG:__main__:Sleeping for 33.919725732684476
```

**log.txt Output:**

```
DEBUG:__main__:Liking 1494171280764517709
DEBUG:__main__:Sleeping for 33.919725732684476
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `ts` before the `tee` so that the timestamp is added to the output before it's written to the file:

```
python ig.py |& ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee -a log.txt
```